# Case record if the case is lost (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law

How can I search for a case record if the case is lost?
It was originally filed by the trustee as a small claim but might have been moved up to a higher court due to the complexity.

The case was not about me but the judgement has serious implications for me and my neighbours.

Comment: What do you mean "the case is lost"? Do you mean that someone else won the case? If you mean that the case record is lost, who lost it? Also, do you really need to whole case record or just the judgment?

Answer (score 1):

If you have lost a case record, you can try the following steps to find it:

1. Contact the Court Clerk at: Get in touch with the clerk of the court in the jurisdiction where the case was first filed. They might be able to help you find the case file.
2. Utilize the Court's Online Database: Case records can be found in many courts' electronic databases. The docket or case index, which can provide details about the case's status, parties, and court appearances, may be included in this.
3. Obtain a Copies of the File: You can request a copy of the file from the Clerk of Court if the case record cannot be found in the electronic database. This service may be available for a fee in some jurisdictions.
4. Examine the Files of the Appellate Court: If the case was moved to a higher court because of its complexity, you can look for information about the case in the records of the appellate court. This can frequently be accomplished by contacting the Clerk of Court or visiting the website of the appellate court.
5. Hire a lawyer: You might want to think about hiring an attorney to help you find the case record if you are unable to do so on your own. You may be able to locate the case record and gain a better understanding of the judgment's impact on your situation with the assistance of an attorney who has the knowledge and resources necessary to do so.

It is essential to keep in mind that it may be challenging to ascertain the case's outcome if the case record has been lost. It might be in your best interest to speak with an attorney if you are worried about how the decision will affect your situation.